# How to read any data from database on its write trigger on one of its child in firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image]

I have put trigger on 'pojo' node,whenever some change happens, it get triggered. I can access its child, but how do I access following location?

Value at this location :

> /XVbW8ED5DmTUerEYZZykp1GN2TO2/deviceToken

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.ok = functions.database.ref("/{uid}/messages/{key}/pojo")
   .onWrite(event => {
      var snap = event.data;
      var b = snap.child("admin").val();
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When triggering a database function, Cloud Functions passes in the data from the point on which is was triggered downwards. To get any data from another location in the database, you need to read that data in your code.

#### Access nearby data by navigating from `event.data.ref`

So if you have a sibling `admin`:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.ok=functions.database.ref("/{uid}/messages/{key}/pojo")
.onWrite(event =>{

  var snap = event.data;
  return snap.ref.parent.child("admin").once("value").then((adminSnapshot) {
    var adminVal = adminSnapshot.val();
    // TODO: do something with the adminVal and return a value or a promise
  });

}
```

To read a value from a completely unrelated path, you have two options:

1. Use `event.data.ref.root` or `event.data.adminRef.root`.
2. Use the Admin SDK, which is already included in most samples.

#### Use `event.data.ref.root` or `event.data.adminRef.root`

You can also start building a path from the root, by using `event.data.ref.root` or `event.data.adminRef.root`. The difference between these two options is that `event.data.ref` has the same access permissions as the user that triggered the functions, while `event.data.adminRef` has full access to the entire database.

A simple example of this is say that you have a global `admin` node that you want to access:

```
exports.ok=functions.database.ref("/{uid}/messages/{key}/pojo")
.onWrite(event =>{

  var root = event.data.ref.root;
  return root.child("admin").once("value").then((adminSnapshot) {
    var adminVal = adminSnapshot.val();
    // TODO: do something with the adminVal and return a value or a promise
  });

}
```

#### Use the Admin SDK, which is already included in most samples.

Alternatively you can start with the Admin SDK, which is already included in your snippet:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.ok=functions.database.ref("/{uid}/messages/{key}/pojo")
.onWrite(event =>{

  var snap = event.data;
  admin.database().ref('XVbW8ED5DmTUerEYZZykp1GN2TO2/deviceToken').once("value").then(function(tokenSnapshot) {
    var deviceToken = tokenSnapshot.val();
  });

}
```

See also [this section of the Firebase documentation for another example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#add_the_addmessage_function).

This last approach also works with other trigger types, e.g. in HTTP triggered functions. Since these functions **don't** get `event.data.ref`, the Admin SDK is your only option here.

Comment: i want value at '/XVbW8ED5DmTUerEYZZykp1GN2TO2/deviceToken'

Comment: OK. I added a snippet for that too.

Comment: do we have to return "admin.database().ref('XVbW8ED5DmTUerEYZZykp1GN2TO2/deviceToken').once("value").then((tokenSnapshot) {
    var deviceToken = tokenSnapshot.val();
  });

Comment: return admin.database().ref('XVbW8ED5DmTUerEYZZykp1GN2TO2/deviceToken').once("value").then((tokenSnapshot) {
    var deviceToken = tokenSnapshot.val();
  });

Comment: I think you missed the keywork 'function' in the snippet to read the deviceToken. It should be
admin.database().ref('XVbW8ED5DmTUerEYZZykp1GN2TO2/deviceToken').once("value").then(function(tokenSnapshot) {
    var deviceToken = tokenSnapshot.val();
  });

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Fixed.

Comment: @puf you need to return the promise (`return admin.database()...`) to make sure the function executes normally.

Comment: Since the original code was unclear about the use of the token, I decided to leave it incomplete. I expect a call to FCM, in which case the return should come from there and bubble up. I've added a TODO to the code to make this explicit.