# update value when change in event using firebase functions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I wan to update an "uniqueCode" value when there is any change on "events" by firebase-functions

below is how firebase db looks

[image]

below is my code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.ok=functions.database.ref("/events/")
.onWrite(event =>{

  var snap = admin.database().ref('uniqueCode');
  snap++;
  admin.database().ref('uniqueCode').set(snap);
});
```

but if I change any in "events", no value is changing of "uniqueCode"

Finally with help of @Frank van Puffelen I have done by below code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.ok=functions.database.ref("/events/")
.onWrite(event =>{

admin.database().ref('uniqueCode').once("value", function(snapshot) {
  var value = snapshot.val();
  value++;
  admin.database().ref('uniqueCode').set(value);
  console.log("The read success: " + snapshot.val());
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});

});
```

Comment: You first need to read the current value, then update it,, and finally write the updated value back to the database. See my recent answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321441/how-to-read-any-data-from-database-on-its-write-trigger-on-one-of-its-child-in-f/44323007#44323007. Note that there we import the `admin` module, which is Firebase's Admin SDK, and use it to access the database.

Comment: woow @FrankvanPuffelen feel happy as answer directly from you

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sir, but function is not triggering

Comment: I am reading value by var value = firebase.database.ref('uniqueCode');
is this not correct way?

Comment: That doesn't read any value. It just creates a reference to a location in the database. To read a value, you need to attach a listener with `on()` or `once()` as my linked answer shows. Please study that answer and the [relevant documentation for the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data).