# Firebase function access not related data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm searching for a way when I can access database elements not related to my trigger data in firebase functions.
As I see I can set(...) things on other elements but unfortunately I can't just read the values out of the elements, for example this doesn't work:

```
event.data.adminRef.root.child('bettings/'+matchId+'/begin_at').val()
```

I know about the 'proper way' to get those things, which is like:

```
var match = event.data.adminRef.root.child('bettings/' + matchId + '/begin_at');
match.once('value',function(snapshot){
    var alma = snapshot.val();
    console.log('alma val');
    console.log(alma);
});
```

But I hope there is a better/easier way then write such codes all the time I need something out of my current scope.

Update: it is not a duplicate of [How to read any data from database on its write trigger on one of its child in firebase functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321441/how-to-read-any-data-from-database-on-its-write-trigger-on-one-of-its-child-in-f) !
I know about ....once(..), and that I can access the values through promises but I need a much more quicker way, because sometimes it takes about 10 seconds, which is really slow and the user won't get the response in time!

Comment: The additional info in your question, while valuable, is unrelated to the initial question. You stated *I can't just read the values out of the elements* and the linked post is a duplicate. If there's an issue with performance, that would be a very different question. As a side note, if your Firebase read is taking 10 seconds, you have something causing it that's most likely unrelated to Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where you access data from a specific database node and perform a task with the value jobowner:

```
let jobRef = admin.database().ref(`/jobs/${jobid}`);
const jo = jobRef.child("owner").once('value');
return Promise.all([jo]).then(r => {
  const jobowner = r[0];
  const promises = [];
  let key = admin.database().ref(`/jobowners/${jobowner}`).set({
    value: 'test',
    other: false
  });
  promises.push(room);
  return Promise.all(promises);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but you still use the .once and promises... the problem here is the speed, because sometimes waiting for this promises, once and whatsoever takes about 10 seconds... which is too slow for me.